# How can I make My model unique?

Tags: dbaccess

```
#import <SharkORM.h>

@class DLRSSGroup;
@class DLUser;


@interface DLRSS : SRKObject

@property NSString *r_id;

//RSS的名称
@property NSString *r_name;

//RSS的描述
@property NSString *r_discrip;

//RSS的图标
@property NSString *r_iconUrl;

//RSS的订阅链接
@property NSString *r_feedUrl;

//RSS的访问链接
@property NSString *r_linkUrl;

//RSS的开关
@property BOOL r_open;

//外键，DLRSSGroup的id
@property DLRSSGroup *rg_id_fk;

//外键，RSS的作者id
@property DLUser *u_id_fk;


@end
```

Evertime i get item from the server, the same item will insert into the  dataTable, so there are many same items in the datatable.
How can I make r_id or r_name unique????

Answer (score 0):

The unique key on an SRKObject is the Id column, so to work in the way you suggest is possible only with a query first.  Retrieve an object, if it is not in existence then create a new one.

Example:

```
SRKObject* myObject = [[[[[DLRSS query] whereWithFormat:@"r_id = %@", r_idValue] limit:1] fetch] firstObject];
if (!myObject) {
   myObject = [DLRSS new];
}
```

Or, if you don't fancy doing this everywhere, then put it into the object itself.

```
- (BOOL)entityWillInsert {
   // count operations are very fast here
   if ([[[[DLRSS query] whereWithFormat:@"r_id = %@", self.r_id] limit:1] count]) {
      // setting the Id column to an existing one will cause  areplace when `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO DLRSS` is triggered.
      self.Id = [[[[[DLRSS query] whereWithFormat:@"r_id = %@", self.r_id] limit:1] distinct:@"Id"] objectAtIndex:0];
   }
}
```

Comment: `#import "DLRSS.h"

@implementation DLRSS

@dynamic r_id, r_name, r_discrip, r_iconUrl, r_feedUrl, r_linkUrl, r_open;

//外键
@dynamic rg_id_fk, u_id_fk;

+ (NSArray*)uniquePropertiesForClass {
    return @[@"r_id"];
}

@end` can I write it like this?@Adrian_H

Comment: You can,  but that will just fail the write which is no good for what is essentially a merge from a network source.

Comment: I use the method as you say, now the data is not repeated, but now I can't update the data which use the same Id. help!@Adrian_H